# WPF Richtextbox show HTML text in correct format

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, rtf

I'm setting html text with tags to richtextbox but it's not displaing in correct format. Is there a way to show it in correct format?

Comment: What have you given so far? Show us some sample.

Answer (score 1):

RichTextBox control in WPF doesn't support HTML tag. It's clearly stated in MSDN Library.

> Pasting HTML content into a RichTextBox might result in unexpected
>   behavior because RichTextBox uses RTF format rather than directly
>   using HTML format.

See this in .NET 3.0 and 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=VS.90).aspx

And also this link in .NET 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Frame` WPF control to display HTML correctly. If you have a stream of HTML text then use `WebBrowser` control. [WPF Web Browser using NavigateToStream() and changing "about:blank" in printout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909648/wpf-web-browser-using-navigatetostream-and-changing-aboutblank-in-printout)